# Return value in Observe Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, observable

How to return a value from Observer?

```
    val clockInAndOutTime = ClockInAndOutTime()
    clockInAndOutTime.id = 12
    longToast("Name " +displayName(clockInAndOutTime.id.toString()))

 private fun displayName(userId: String): String {

        var name = ""
        organizationViewModel.refreshList()
        organizationViewModel.organization.observe(
            this, Observer { resource ->
                resource?.data.let {
                    it?.forEach { organization ->
                        if (organization.user_id == userId) {
                            name = organization.user_name!!
                            Log.d(TAG, "name is $name")
                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG,"not found")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        return name
    }
```

In displayName function, we are able to get the name, but in toast, the `Name` is always display empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767 have a look at this answer of mine please, it's the same concept as this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't do that. invoke a function inside your `Observer`

```
private fun displayName(userId: String, onNameFound: (String) -> Unit): String {

    var name = ""
    organizationViewModel.refreshList()
    organizationViewModel.organization.observe(
        this, Observer { resource ->
            resource?.data.let {
                it?.forEach { organization ->
                    if (organization.user_id == userId) {
                        name = organization.user_name!!
                        Log.d(TAG, "name is $name")
                        onNameFound(name)
                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG,"not found")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
    return name
}
```

and then call it as

```
displayName(clockInAndOutTime.id.toString()) { longToast("Name $it") }
```

Comment: What should I add for this line `displayName(clockInAndOutTime.id.toString()` ?

Comment: `displayName(clockInAndOutTime.id.toString()) {  longToast("Name $it") }` should do it

Comment: It need  me to pass one more parameter.

Comment: what version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: 1.3.31-release-Studio3.4-1

Comment: I have the `1.3.41`. Check if upgrading fixes your problem. On my laptop compiles fine

Comment: do a gist and send me the link if you want

Comment: Why I add a toast to display the name after the lambda, it display empty?

Comment: could `organization.user_name`  be empty? Are you using the `Activity` context to show the `Toast?